# How to pass JS value from apex to inputText in visualforce?

Tags: visualforce

I would like to pass value to  from apex.
1.I get the value from javascript.
2.I want to pass the js value to apex.
3.**By Apex constructor**, I want to get the js value.
4.inputText in Visualforce page display js value.
What should I do?

Sample.vfp

```
<apex:page controller="SampleController" showHeader="true" sidebar="false" id="page">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection>            
            <apex:form id="form">
                <apex:inputText label="ここにjsの値を入れたい" value="{!ctlpara}" />
                <apex:commandButton onclick="{jsfunc('hoge')}" value="実行"/>

                <apex:actionFunction name="actfunc" action="{!ctlfunc}" reRender="dummy">
                    <apex:param name="actprm" value="" />
                </apex:actionFunction>

            </apex:form>
        </apex:pageBlockSection> 
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var id = 'bbb';
    alert(id);
    actfunc(id);
    function jsfunc(jsprm){
        // いろいろ処理...。
        actfunc(jsprm);
    }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

SampleController.apxc

```
public class SampleController {
    public string ctlpara{get;set;}

    //コンストラクタ
    public SampleController(){
        this.ctlpara = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('actprm');
    }

    public pagereference ctlfunc(){
        ctlpara = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('actprm');
        // いろいろ処理...。
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this, just make sure you onclick should not command button which actully try to call server-side directly.

```
<apex:actionFunction name="doAction" action="{!someMethod}" />
<button onclick="doAction(); return false;">Do Action!</button>
```

Comment: Thank you!  
Can I pass value without clicking button?